# ggplot and names: is it possible to have bold characters?

Tags: r, ggplot2, text, fonts, size

I'm trying to draw map. Is there a way to write the name of the cities in bold within the map? ( i've found only the way to choose the size ). This is my script

```
right_join(prov2022, dataset, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `real wage`))+
  geom_sf(data = ~ subset(., COD_REG == 7 | COD_REG >= 1  & COD_REG <= 3)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  geom_sf_text(data = ~ subset(., COD_REG == 7 ), aes(label = city_name), size = 3) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( "#FFFFFF","#FFFF00", "#FF0000", "#000000")) +
  geom_blank()
```

i'd like to have the `city_name` in bold, but in `geom_sf_text(data = ~ subset(., COD_REG == 7 ), aes(label = city_name), size = 3)`  i cannot find the way to do it.... (increase the size is not a good option in my case bacause i've borders that not to be crossed)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply use `fontface = "bold"` in `geom_sf_text`

```r
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(df) +
  geom_sf(fill = "white") +
  geom_sf_text(aes(label = lab), size = 5, fontface = "bold")
```

### [image]

**Reproducible example**

```r
library(sf)

df <- st_polygon(list(cbind(c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0), c(0, 0, 1, 1, 0)))) |>
  st_sfc(crs = "WGS84") |>
  st_as_sf() |>
  within(lab <- "Bold text")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use plotmath expression "bold(<city_name>)" and parse = TRUE

```
  right_join(prov2022, dataset, by = "COD_PROV") %>% 
  mutate(city_name = paste0("bold(\"", city_name, "\")")) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(fill = `real wage`))+
  geom_sf(data = ~ subset(., COD_REG == 7 | COD_REG >= 1  & COD_REG <= 3)) +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title=element_blank())+
  geom_sf_text(data = ~ subset(., COD_REG == 7 ), aes(label = city_name), size = 3, 
               parse = TRUE) +
  scale_fill_gradientn(colors = c( "#FFFFFF","#FFFF00", "#FF0000", "#000000")) +
  geom_blank()
```

Note: cannot test because have not reproducible data.

Comment: I was so close to a similar answer!

Comment: Hi guys, thanks for the answer, but it seems that doens't work.. R answers `Error in `geom_sf_text()`:
! Problem while converting geom to grob.
ℹ Error occurred in the 2nd layer.
Caused by error in `parse()`:
! <text>:1:9: unexpected symbol
1: bold(La Spezia
            ^
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.`

Comment: Yes, i omit to put escaped double quotes. Corrected in the post. Thanks for test it